# Handshake_failure in Ruby when using OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openssl

I'm trying to ignore certs on an https request using net/https in ruby.

I'm passing the  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE but it's still giving me a handshake error:

```
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,        
     :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https',
     :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
     :ssl_version => :TLSv1_2) do |http|
       request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri
       response = http.request request
   end
```

The output:

```
Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

We're using the following:

```
ruby '2.3.3', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '9.1.15.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.10'
```

Comment: It's a known bug: https://github.com/jruby/jruby-openssl/issues/137

Comment: does `uri.scheme == 'https'` return true when you get this error?

Comment: Is this only a jruby bug? It seems to work for me in standard ruby.